# How to call isValid() function in the viewmodel using knockout-validation

Tags: knockout-validation

I have a viewmodel defined following:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.property1 = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.property2 = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.property1();
    });
    self.form_onsubmit = function (form) {
        if (!self.isValid()) {
            console.log("error");
        }
        return false;
    };
};

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(new ViewModel());
});
```

when i call the `form_onsubmit` function, an error occured:

```
TypeError: self.isValid is not a function
if (!self.isValid()) {
```

how to solve it, thanks^^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add

`self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);`

to your viewmodel